# Using angular chart with bootstrap 3

Tags: angularjs, charts, pug, angular-chart

I'm trying to include an [angular chart](https://github.com/maxklenk/angular-chart) component.

, inside of a panel from bootstrap, i'm using a node template engine jade, this part of code is where i'm trying to put the chart:

```
 .col-md-7
  .row
    .col-md-11
      .panel.panel-default.content
        angularchart(dataset="dataset" schema="schema" options="options")
```

But the chart is outside the panel, like the image.[image]

Is there a way to fit into the panel?

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting the width of the chart to 90%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the styles for the `<angularchart>` tag are set:

```
angularchart {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
}
```

The current release includes these styles inline. Check out the [upgrade guide](https://github.com/maxklenk/angular-chart#upgrade-02x-to-030) to switch to this improved version.